# Make work computer accessible from home

Tags: routing, openvpn

First of all, my work computer is my computer and it's at an office I share. 
 I don't have an employer whose policies the following could possibly violate.

The office internet is NATed and I can't forward any ports to my computer which runs Ubuntu.  I want to be able to SSH into my work computer from home and also access web apps (like Rstudio server, for instance).  I'm thinking the best way to do that is to setup an OpenVPN server from my home Tomato router and then setup my work computer to always connect to that.  What I don't want though is for my work computer to route all of its traffic through the VPN.  In fact, I don't want it to route any traffic through this VPN (my home uplink speed would be quite a bottleneck).

Q1: Is there a better way of allowing SSH and webapp access to my work computer than having it connect to a VPN that I don't know.

Q2:  (Assuming answer to Q1 is no)  If I were following [this guide](https://vpncritic.com/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-server-with-tomato-openvpn/)?  Would I simply omit the `route...` and `redirect...` lines in the client config?

```
remote www.yourdomain.net *
port 1194
dev tap
secret staticvpn.key
proto udp
comp-lzo
route-gateway 192.168.1.1 **
redirect-gateway def 1
float
route-method exe
route-delay 2
```

Comment: If the network is NATed, then unless you are an Administrator on the network, you cannot make the required configuration changes to the configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound: How so? You don't need configuration changes just to connect to a VPN server.

Comment: @grawity - Two networks have to be configured to port forward the traffic on the port the VPN server is configured to use.  My assumption is the VPN server is behind the second router.  Perhaps I don't understand the user's network configuration as well as I thought I did.

Comment: @Ramhound: The VPN server is described to be at home (where the router is configurable) and accept inbound connections from work (where it isn't). Once the outer connection is established, it can carry inner traffic in both directions. It's a typical "reverse tunnel" setup.